# Django template cache - Dynamic key based on template variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cache

I need to store template cache using a parameter as prefix.

Es.
With:

```
{% cache 5 :name:variable1: variable_y variable_z %}
    <p> {{variable1}} </p>
{% endcache %}
```

where variable1 is a string

I need to store:

```
:1:template.cache:name:"variable1 value":.0ecadd093a225ba502d3f6490e19b4
```

Actually I obtain:

```
:1:template.cache:name:variable1:.0ecadd093a225ba502d3f6490e19b4
```

where variable1 is the variable name.

There's a way?
Thanks

Comment: You could pass ready to use key from the view.

Comment: I pass variable1 from the view and it'is a string. I would like write string value in redis key but acutally i obtain the variable name ("variable1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using [Django Advanced Cache Templatetag](https://github.com/twidi/django-adv-cache-tag).

**For python 3:** `pip install django-adv-cache-tag`

**For python 2 support:** `pip install 'django-adv-cache-tag<1.0'`

Add `'adv_cache_tag'` to `INSTALLED_APPS=[...]`

Add `ADV_CACHE_RESOLVE_NAME = True` in your settings.py

Change `{% load cache %}` with `{% load adv_cache %}`

**From documentation:**

With `ADV_CACHE_RESOLVE_NAME` set to `True`, you can do this if you have
a variable named fragment_name in your context:

```
{% cache 0 fragment_name obj.pk obj.date_last_updated %}
```

And if you want to pass a name, you have to surround it by quotes:

```
{% cache 0 "myobj_main_template" obj.pk obj.date_last_updated %}
```

With `ADV_CACHE_RESOLVE_NAME` set to `False`, the default, the name is
always seen as a string, but if surrounded by quotes, they are removed.